# How to sort index with groupby based on another column count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have challenge to sort with groupby, After I have done groupby on 'level_3' column I'm struggling to sort the value of index (level_3) based on the count of column 'LHR Item Count' so I want index(level_3) to start wit '010' first, then '006' because '010' has more 'LHR Item Count'

```
sor = WMS_missing.groupby('level_3')
sor.apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))
```

[image]

The end result would be :

[image]

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, with .join function

```
x = WMS_missing.join(WMS_missing.groupby('level_3')['LHR Item Count'].count(), on='level_3', rsuffix='_r')

z = x.groupby('level_3')

z.apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).sort_values(by='LHR Item Count_r', ascending=False)
```